# Slipstream Office in Windows installation Setup

Tags: windows

How can I run a silent installation program after the Windows Setup from windows 7 and 8?
Because I will slipstream Microsoft Office 2013 in the installation.

Comment: usually it is the `/Q` flag, which stands for "quiet".

Comment: That's not what I mean, I would run a program after the Windows Installation Setup, Sorry for my bad english